# "Interactions" (and syntax) between JSON and Javascript arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs

I'm not really good with JSON; maybe I didn't get the JSON concept so well to get out of this, so I'm asking.

I have a function in AngularJS that contains an array; this array should be automatically filled with content from a JSON page in my server. The array is composed by object made in this way:

```
var a = [{ id: 0, name: '', date:'', content: ''}, ...]
```

My question is: how should create the JSON object to respect my array syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the function built into JavaScript to [convert data structures to JSON](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.12.3):

```
var json = JSON.stringify(a);
```

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. OP wants to design a JSON response and use it to populate an array, not turning a data structure into JSON... Maybe I misunderstood the question though.

Comment: @PeterHerdenborg — The OP said they had an array which contains some objects and wanted to create JSON. It could be interpreted that way too though, it is not a clear question.

Comment: Ok (thank you for the quick answer), now i got the JSON object, but how can i trasform the string in array using $http.get('myUrl.json'), where myUrl is where my file is.

Comment: `JSON.parse(yourstring)`

Comment: @PeterHerdenborg you got the point. If i have the JSON object, how can i turn back into array?

Comment: There's no such thing as a JSON Object. To turn a string containing JSON into an array see my last comment.

Comment: Thank you @Quentin, the functions JSON.stringify() and JSON.parse() gave me all what i needed. ;)